# Accessing a child's constant from the parent's class

Tags: ruby

If a child inherits from the parent, it inherits the parents methods as well.

So how come an inherited method can't access the child's constants?

Example -

```
class Parent
  def my_method
    puts "Value of FOO is #{FOO}"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  FOO = "bar"
end

Child.new.my_method #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Parent::FOO
```

Doesn't the inherited method run "inside" the child class?

How can I get around this?

Comment: You can get around it by using `self.class::FOO` instead of `FOO` in `my_method`

Comment: @maxpleaner, could you post that as answer, perhaps with mention of `self`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm a bit embarassed to say I don't have a good explanation of why that works, all I know is it does :D

Comment: @max, if `c=Child.new` and `c.my_method` is involked, `self` is `c` inside `my_method`. I think it's as simple as that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland but then why can you access Child::Foo in Child's instance method?

Comment: @max, you suggested  using `self.class::FOO` in `Parent#my_method`. If `c = Child.new` and `c.my_method` is executed, `self` equals `c` within `my_method`, so `self.class::FOO => c.class::FOO => Child::FOO => 'bar'`, the same as if `my_method`'s owner were `Child`. No?

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't. When you call `Child.new.my_method` it looks for the `FOO` constant in `Parent` and upwards.

I'm not going to question your approach and just provide you with a way to do what you want:

```
class Parent
  def self.inherited(other)
    other.define_singleton_method(:my_method) do
      puts "Value of FOO is #{other.const_get(:FOO)}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now whenever you inherit from `Parent` the inherited hook will define a method `my_method` on the subclass. Notice that the scope of the block in the `inherited` method is still the class level scope of `Parent`. That's why I'm directly referencing the subclass (`other`) to get the constant.
A way around this would be to use `other.instance_exec { ... }`.

#### Update

@maxpleaner pointed out (with the explanation provided by @CarySwoveland) that you could also retrieve the class via `self` and then retrieve the constant from it.

I.e., just do

```
class Parent
  def my_method
    puts "Values of FOO is #{self.class.const_get(:FOO)}"
  end
end
```

That works because when calling `child = Child.new; child.my_method` the value of `self` within `my_method` will be `child`. And the class of `child` is obviously `Child` which knows the constant `FOO`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for static methods?